# Filter multiple specific properties from an array of objects into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a big array of objects such as

```
let arr = [
  {name: "name1" , surname: "surname1", age: "22"},
  {name: "name2" , surname: "surname2", age: "23"},
  {name: "name3" , surname: "surname3", age: "24"},
]
```

But i need to filter it so it will be

```
arr = [
  {name: "name1" , surname: "surname1"},
  {name: "name2" , surname: "surname2"},
  {name: "name3" , surname: "surname3"},
]
```

How can i do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [ {name: "name1" , surname: "surname1", age: "22"}, {name: "name2" , surname: "surname2", age: "23"}, {name: "name3" , surname: "surname3", age: "24"} ];

const res = arr.map(({ name, surname }) => ({ name, surname }));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to filter *multiple* properties, you can store the properties to delete inside an array, then loop through it when [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ing and delete the properties:

```js
const propertiesToFilter = ['age']

let arr = [
{name: "name1" , surname: "surname1", age: "22"},
{name: "name2" , surname: "surname2", age: "23"},
{name: "name3" , surname: "surname3", age: "24"},
]

const res = arr.map(e => (propertiesToFilter.forEach(f => delete e[f]), e))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `for-of` with [object-destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring)

```js
for(person of arr){
    const {name, surname} = person;
    res.push({name, surname})
}
```